# how to get email inbox of multiple accounts in one application/service (like unified inbox)?

Tags: java, android

I have tried calling native Email client in android as well as K-9 mail but it shows account list first.then in particular account I am able to get inbox,but i want all inbox in one folder(unified inbox-like in k-9 mail or something related to)so that when i open application,it should show me inbox of accounts that are setup.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What are you trying to do? Write a program that calls an email program, or are you writing your own email program or do you want to modify K9?

Comment: what i want is an application that has multiple email accounts ,but shows in one Common "Inbox".No separate "Inbox" for different accounts.for example, i have acocunts a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com,c@yahoo.com,d@hotmail.com added in my application .Now what i want is in single folder(or named something) "Inbox"  all mails/messages should be there.

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you want to write a program? Or are you looking of a program? In latter case you are wrong here and you should try http://android.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: of course i want to write a program.plus i have k-9 mail source.SO ,
if are there any ways to modify k-9 or build app from scratch.

Comment: ok, but the question is still too broad. All I can say is: Yes it is possible to display all the mail from multiple account in one list, you just have to write it that way. Until you can describe a concrete, elemental problem there is not much more one can say to help.

Comment: thanks for reply...i've been searching on google and only found is how to send,not to receive.Also in Javamail API Android has no documentation available.So how to receive email and store in list?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://thelunchtalk.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/receive-multiple-emails-to-single-inbox-on-android/